# How to determine if two vertices (or two edges) fall on a cycle of a specific length?

Tags: graphs

A **walk** is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which joins a sequence of vertices. A **trail** is a walk in which all edges are distinct.
A **cycle** in a graph is a non-empty trail in which only the first and last vertices are equal.

We know that determining whether two vertices (or two edges) fall on a triangle is relatively easy. However, I am not sure if there are any algorithms for general k-cycles. That is to say, I would like to determine whether two given vertices (or two edges) fall on a cycle of a specific length.

I am not aware of the existence or complexity of such an algorithm. However, I think if the length of the cycle is equal to the order of a graph, it must be NP-hard, because determining whether a graph is Hamiltonian is NP-hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is an input, and the cycle is not allowed to repeat vertices, then as you say, the problem is NP-hard, as it is at least as hard as the Hamiltonian cycle problem (simply set $k$ equal to the number of vertices in the graph).

If $k$ is fixed and small and the cycle is not allowed to repeat vertices, I believe the problem can be solved in polynomial time (but exponential in $k$) by adapting the methods in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19508/5038.

If the cycle is allowed to repeat vertices and edges, then the problem is easy to solve.  Let $A$ denote the adjacency matrix, so that $A_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge $(i,j)$ in the graph and 0 otherwise.  Note that $A^n$ can be computed efficiently using matrix multiplication, and $(A^n)_{ij}$ counts the number of (non-simple) walks from $i$ to $j$ of length $n$ (where vertices and/or edges can be repeated).  It follows that vertices $i,j$ are on the same cycle iff there exists $\ell$ such that $(A^\ell)_{ij}>0$ and $(A^{k-\ell})_{ji}>0$.  This gives an efficient algorithm for your problem in this case.

Comment: I am not sure if it is necessary to first find all k-cycles, and then test one by one whether two vertices or two edges are on a specific k-cycle.